# What does "I cannot but totally agree" mean?

Tags: expressions

What does the phrase/expression "I cannot but totally agree" mean?

The sentence was said after *Person A* had praised *Person B*.

I understand that *Person B* is completely agreeing with what *Person A* said. But Why is *cannot* used at the start? What does it signify?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*But* here means 'except': *I can do nothing **except** totally agree.*

Comment: Does that `cannot` mean that the person telling that sentence cannot do what **Person B** had done, but he agrees with what **Person A** said?

Comment: @VenkateshKumar: Yes, it means that the speaker agrees with A.

Comment: @VenkateshKumar- the *cannot* does not mean anything about whether the speaker could have also done what Person B did.  It means that the speaker cannot disagree with what A said- he has no choice except to agree.

Comment: It means fully agreeing...

Answer (score 1):

Do you remember your Math classes at school when multiplying two negative numbers you get positive answer. It is the same here. I have googled about more information and I have found that that is called **Negative Polarity** (the grammatical character of a word or phrase, such as ever or any, that may normally only be used in a semantically or syntactically negative or interrogative context ).

The full phrase is **cannot help but do something** and it is formal. You can make it less formal omitting help or using can't instead of cannot.

Similar idiom is  **I am forced to something, though** .
Example:    I am forced to the conclusion that Fred is guilty, though I'd rather not believe it .

Answer (score 0):

I cannot (disagree with you) but totally agree